# json_decode is not working properly in magento 2.4.0

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.0

I am trying to decode the JSON in normal string and print that in the info log in Magento 2.4.0 but I am getting nothing in the info log. Adding the code below anyone please suggest a solution for this.

**Code I am using**

```
public function execute()
{
    $result = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();
    $isSuccess = $this->tracking->createApi();
    $jsonresponse = json_decode($isSuccess); // decoding here
    $this->logger->info(var_dump($jsonresponse)); // trying to print in info log
    return $result->setData(['success' => $isSuccess]);
}
```

$isSuccess - this variable has the below JSON data

Coveolog.INFO: {"sourceType":"PUSH","id":"dsspartnersorggrc3y48w-uk7awlmkozpufpe6pwaeoycmpy","name":"DSS-Coveo_M2-Integration-B2C-product-en_US","sourceVisibility":"SHARED","customParameters":{},"information":{"sourceStatus":{"type":"CREATING","timestamp":1617776580670,"allowedOperations":["DELETE"]},"numberOfDocuments":0,"documentsTotalSize":0},"pushEnabled":true,"onPremisesEnabled":false,"streamEnabled":false,"logicalIndex":"default","preConversionExtensions":[],"postConversionExtensions":[],"permissions":{"permissionLevels":[{"name":"Source Specified Permissions","permissionSets":[{"name":"Shared","permissions":[{"allowed":true,"identityType":"GROUP","identity":"*@*","securityProvider":"Email Security Provider"}]}]}]},"urlFilters":[{"filter":"*","includeFilter":true,"filterType":"WILDCARD"}],"ocrFileTypes":[],"resourceId":"dsspartnersorggrc3y48w-uk7awlmkozpufpe6pwaeoycmpy"} [] []

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't need to use `var_dump()` when logging something in a file; the function is used when you want to dump info on the browser instead.
2. When decoding, I would suggest you use the function like this `json_decode($isSuccess, true)` so that your variable's content is properly converted to associative array and not object.

Comment: I tried as per your comment, but I am not getting the result.

Comment: hmm ok, well i am not entirely sure how is your message formed, maybe i am missing something.

Comment: I am writing this code inside the controller is that correct as per Magento standards?

Comment: can you also try this? `json_decode(trim($isSuccess), true);`?

Comment: this is also not working.

Comment: maan, i was thinking that maybe there is an encoding issue there, which is still not excluded. do you know how is the encoding done?